# '=' left operand must be an l-value

Tags: c++, pointers

I have searched for this multiple times and still cannot find an answer to this problem. I keep getting an error saying `error C2106: '-=' : left operand must be l-value`

My code looks like this

```
case 1:
            mItemCost = 4;
            if (player.getGold() >= 4){
                cout << "You have bought a dagger which replaces your current weapon!" << endl;
                player.getGold() -= mItemCost; // Error here
                player.getWeapon().mName = "Dagger";
                player.getDamageRange().mLow = 1; // Error here
                player.getDamageRange().mHigh = 4; // Error here
            }
```

player is a pointer to another class. I would be really grateful for any help. Thank you :D

Comment: "Solution: change the return type of `getGold()`." This answer contains about as much information as your question. Please, add all the necessary information to produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); in particular, the definition of `player` and its type.

Comment: Usually, it would be `player.setGold(player.getGold()-mItemCost);` etc.

Comment: Please show the declaration of the functions involved.

Comment: You cannot assign values to a getter method. For setting the value ypu have to use the setter method.

Comment: or implement a `-=` operator for the player's class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to a method call, which is illegal unless the return value is a reference.

You probably meant something like

```
player.setGold(player.getGold() - mItemCost);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign to the return value of a function and based on the error, the function does not return a reference.

You have two options to fix this.

1. Write (if necessary) and use the appropriate setters instead for each error.

   ```
   player.setGold(player.getGold() - mItemCost)
   ```
2. Have the getters return references instead.

Consider this simple program which reproduces the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo = 0;
int getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
int main(){
    getFoo() = 5; // error here.
}
```

We can fix the error by changing the signature of the function to return a reference.

```
int& getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
```

Note that this is **not** the idiomatic way to do it, but *will* work.